# How to create a generating function / closed form from this recurrence?

Tags: number-theory, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

Let $f_n$ = $f_{n-1} + n + 6$ where $f_0 = 0$.

I know $f_n = \frac{n^2+13n}{2}$ but I want to pretend I don't know this. How do I correctly turn this into a generating function / derive the closed form?

Comment: For this problem there’s really no need for generating functions at all: by inspection $$f_n=\sum_{k=1}^nk+6n=\frac{n(n+1)}2+6n=\frac{n^2+13n}2\;.$$

Comment: +1 that is why I posted two answers. In fact it's harder to find the closed form using generating functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
G(x) &=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n x^n \\
&=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty (f_{n-1} + n + 6) x^n \\
&=& \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{n-1} x^n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty n x^ n + \sum_{n=1}^\infty 6 x^n \\
&=& x G(x) + x \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right) + 6 \frac{x}{1-x}
\end{array}$$

So $$G(x) = \frac{6x^2 - 7x}{x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x - 1} = 7x + 15x^2 + 24x^3 + 34x^4 + 45x^5 + \cdots$$

Comment: Can you explain the last step at all, how you get to 7x + ... etc

Comment: @user54089, long division or use the recurrence relation (or both and check they are the same to make sure you didn't make a mistake).

Comment: How do you get from the generating function to the closed form?

Comment: @robjohn, my comment says "+1 that is why I posted two answers. In fact it's harder to find the closed form using generating functions." I recommend against using generating functions to find the closed form. I have shown how to find the closed form directly from the recurrence in another answer.

Comment: @caveman: If you are interested, I have derived the general term from the generating function using the appropriate binomial expansions.

Answer (score 5):

Let $$F(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}f_nx^n=f_0+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_nx^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(f_{n-1}+n+6)x^n=$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n-1}x^{n}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}6x^n=$$

$$=x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_{n-1}x^{n-1}+x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}nx^{n-1}+x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}6x^{n-1}=$$

$$=xF(x)+x\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}+6x\frac{1}{1-x}$$
Generating function is
$$F(x)=\frac{x+6x(1-x)}{(1-x)^3}=\frac{7x-6x^2}{(1-x)^3}$$

Comment: What is wrong there. Why downvote

Comment: because it's exactly the same argument as my answer

Comment: it's a good answer but it's been written already

Comment: my answer is independent and is more explicit then your

Comment: Now you have downvoted my answers.

Comment: I regret helping you out by telling you why I downvoted.

Comment: why you now downvote my 4 last answers

Comment: @caveman: If you really did downvote Adi Dani's other answers that is just petty. And leads to loss of sympathy. For your information: The forum software will catch that, overturn the downvotes, and hit you with a suspension. Don't do that!

Comment: I flagged him for plagarism as well. @JyrkiLahtonen, I upvoted some of his other answers after downvoting this to balance, then I saw what he did and changed balanced it again.

Comment: @caveman: AdiDani's answer uses generating functions. It is not clear how your answer was derived, so it is hard to see that the argument is the same.

Comment: @robjohn, my answer is exactly the same I posted two to this question.

Comment: @cveman:you think that generating functions are your patent if so I will delete my answer

Comment: @caveman: Ah, I was just looking at the one above. I didn't see the other.

Comment: @AdiDani, the issue is that (1) you posted exactly the same argument as me afterwards. (2) you downvoted my answers after I told you why (in order to help you) I downvoted yours.

Comment: **Please** move this discussion to meta.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez, meta questions are too eagerly closed by people who are not moderators.

Comment: If that happens, tell moderators and we will deal with it—what is clear is that this discussion should not happen *here*. In any case, the meta question on the subject was actually closed/deleted by you!

Comment: For me the discussion is considered closed.

Comment: @AdiDani: How do you get from the generating function to the closed form?

Comment: Question is to find generating function. How to find closed form from there for the moment I can't because the g.f is to complicated. From comment of Brian Scott we can see how to derive closed form directly without use of g.f

Comment: @caveman, I do not think it was unfairly closed: it is the prerrogative of users with sufficient rep to vote to close. In any case, and *again*, all this is off-topic here. **Please** use the meta site for this.

Comment: @AdiDani: I guess it depends on how you read "How do I correctly turn this into a generating function / derive the closed form?" I read it as a two part question. I have posted a derivation starting from the generating function.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to derive the generating function for $f_n$. Write the recurrence as

$$f_n-f_{n-1}=n+6$$.

The RHS has the following generating function:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (n+6) x^n = \frac{x (7-6 x)}{(1-x)^2}$$

Let $f(x)$ be the GF of $f_n$.  Then from the above recurrence:

$$f(x) - x f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n x^n - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f_{n-1} x^n = \frac{x (7-6 x)}{(1-x)^2}$$

because $f_0=0$.  Therefore

$$f(x) = \frac{x (7-6 x)}{(1-x)^3}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$f_0 = 0,\; f_n = f_{n-1} + n + 6$$

so $$f_{n+1} = \sum_{i=0}^n (i + 6) = T(n) + 6n = \frac{n^2 + 13n}{2}$$

Answer (score 3):

In two answers, it is derived that the generating function is
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{7x-6x^2}{(1-x)^3}
&=x\left(\frac1{(1-x)^3}+\frac6{(1-x)^2}\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{-3}{k}x^{k+1}+6\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\binom{-2}{k}x^{k+1}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k-1}\left(\binom{-3}{k-1}+6\binom{-2}{k-1}\right)x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\binom{k+1}{k-1}+6\binom{k}{k-1}\right)x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left(\binom{k+1}{2}+6\binom{k}{1}\right)x^k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^2+13k}{2}x^k\\
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, we get the general term is $f_k=\dfrac{k^2+13k}{2}$

Comment: Nice robjohn.+1